# Copy a directory including all files from a stream to another

Tags: stream, directory, copy, clearcase-ucm

I would have a question related to copy directory's between streams in UCM.

For example I have 2 streams included in the same project, lets name streams A and B.
Stream A was created a directory "`my folder`" which includes several sub directories and files.
I want to copy directory "`my folder`" including the entire content to stream B.

Can someone help me? What alternative do I have?

With Merge Manager it's not working, because I have to choose which directory/files from Stream B to be merged(but "`my folder`" is on Stream A), to create new directory and files is not working because of "evil twin".

Answer (score 0):

You need *first* to merge the parent folder which includes "`my folder`"

You can do so simply by launching the version tree of that parent folder in a view on stream B, selecting the version of that folder in stream A (in the version tree), and right-clicking "merge to" the current version in stream B.

That will create a new version of that parent folder (in stream B) which references the "`my folder`": checkin that version to conclude that one merge.

*Then* you can launch merge on the view on stream B, indicating you want to merge stream A.
That will merge "`my folder`", and the sub-folders from "`my folder`" in that destination view on stream B.

---

The [OP AlexM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4255963/alexm) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947558/copy-a-directory-including-all-files-from-a-stream-to-another/26947705#comment42443399_26947705):

> was not working to force merge because on stream B always was saying that merge already done (I merged before several files from Stream A);
>
> I created a stream C at the same level with stream A, doing the same steps on Stream C ...version tree, start merge for parent folder, choose folder to be merged "my folder"...
>
> I could copy "my folder", now I merge all files from Stream A to Stream C.

Comment: Unfortunately is not working, reason no merge to do because was already done. I merged few hours ago some files using findmerge from stream A to B, but the folder was not merged because findmerge is requesting to select which file from stream B to be merged with correspond file from stream A. Another point is that are many folders in stream A and I want to copy in stream B only one particular folder "my folder". Can you please help me?

Comment: @AlexM if the folder wasn't merged, then you need to force the merge of at least one of those sub-folder (as I mentioned, manually, through the version tree), then relaunch a findmerge on that folder.

Comment: @AlexM aloso you need to make sure your folder you want to copy can be merged (through its parent folder): in other word, you need to make sure there isn't already an evil twin for that folder in stream B.

Comment: thank for your answers, was not working to force merge because on stream B always was saying that merge already done(I merged before several files from Stream A); I created a stream C at the same level with stream A, doing the same steps on Stream C ...version tree, start merge for parent folder, choose folder to be merged "my folder"... I could copy "my folder", now I merge all files from Stream A to Stream C

Comment: @AlexM Ok, I have included your solution in the answer for more visibility.